# VB.Net (Crystal Report show/hide fields)

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

Hi I'm using VS2010 with VB.Net as my language... I got stuck as this point about crystal report... report generation where the fields are dynamic i guess?... i can't really put into words.... but this is an analogous scenario

say i have 3 checkboxes.. and in my reports view i also have 3 columns/fields corresponding  to the checkboxes, the columns are shown or hidden depending on checkstate of these 3 checkboxes....

3 checkboxes : {chkName, chkAge, chkSex}
report fields : {Name, Age, Sex}

lets say:

chkName = checked
chkAge = checked
chkSex = checked
report must show Name, Age and Sex

chkName = checked
chkAge = unchecked
chkSex = checked
report must show Name and Sex

chkName = checked
chkAge = unchecked
chkSex = unchecked
report must show Name only

and so on..... hope you got my point..
thanks in advance for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on your field and go into the "Common" tab. There you will be able to see a checkbox with "Suppress". Right next to that you have a button where you can include a formula into it. You just need to pass 3 additional boolean parameters to your report then create a formula in the appropriate field.

```
NOT {?chkName}
```

I used a boolean parameter {?chkName} and if the parameter was true, I return false to the "Suppress"

Hope this helps!

**Edits** I edited the answer thanks to KyleMit

Comment: Why not just `NOT {?chkName}`?